# Strange GET requests in logs

Tags: logging

I'm getting the following GET requests in my apache logs:

```
109.230.251.14 - - [29/Mar/2011:16:28:18 +0100] "GET http://209.191.92.114/config/pwtoken_get?login=jackmcphee232&src=ygodgw&passwd=e59e2240415e6f1aba3da72b8f189f4e&challenge=9TbU_9yfZhKmzlHtK9X4OkQlesTH&md5=1 HTTP/1.0" 404 1226 "-" "-"
```

Any idea what it could be and how is that possibly a get request? That IP address seems to point to Yahoo! I'm very confused.

Comment: You can get such request via proxy server.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  After a long search I found this wiki article that explains what's going on pretty well.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, it's just one of the many automated vulnerability tests constantly peppering web servers these days.

Comment: How do they get the 'GET' to show another domain though?

Comment: Proxying I'd guess. You can mangle URLs in all kinds of ways.

Comment: The GET-request contains the domain name. Therefore, You can connect to any web server and ask for any domain. By using this mechanism, one server with one IP can host several domains (aka Virtual Host). I guess someone or something tried to check, if You server is configured to actually forward the request (which would be a severe security issue).